# git-flow prevent non-release commits from going into master

Tags: git, git-flow

I have started using git-flow branching model in my project.

During release time, I created a new release branch from develop and am allowing only release critical fixes to be committed back to master.

While merging the changes from release to develop branch is there are new commits on develop since release was created, they would have to be merged from develop to release branch first and then from release to develop.

So there is a possibility that these new commits could go to master(latest stable release) if release is is merged to develop first.

Currently, I have frozen the develop branch, so any release critical fixes will have to go to release branch.

But there are a number of feature branches that are waiting to be merged to development.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Please reread https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/